# Moq System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, moq

I get it again and again

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: c => c.ProductMaxLenght
Non-overridable members (here: ConfigurationService.get_ProductMaxLenght) 
may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'
```

When I try call this

```
var configurationService = new Mock<ConfigurationService>();
configurationService.SetupGet(c => c.ProductMaxLenght).Returns(productMaxLength)
```

I call Initialize in Startup and take all data from Configuratiom
Configuration Service:

```
public class ConfigurationService
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private int? _productMaxLength;
        public int? ProductMaxLenght
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_productMaxLength.HasValue)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_productMaxLength));
                }
                return _productMaxLength;
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_configuration));
            _productMaxLength = _configuration.GetValue<int>("ProductsMaxLength");
        }
    }
```

Comment: typo: `public int? ProductMaxLenght` ==> `public int? ProductMaxLength`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the property overridable, so make it `virtual`:

```
public virtual int? ProductMaxLenght  { get ...
```